# Rendering in Django 2.0.2

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

Could anybody help me, please? Django documantation says that 'render_to_response' is not used starting from the 2nd version. I can't display list on my template.

For the model:

```
class Partners(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="pictures", blank=True)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=128, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

i tried both of 2 methods:

```
def partners(request):
    partners_list = Partners.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'partners.html', {'partners_list': partners_list})
```

and

```
def partners(request):
    partners_list = Partners.objects.all()
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'partners.html', {'partners_list': partners_list})
```

Template is:

```
{% for partners in partners_list %}
<div class="col-sm-2" id="partners">
    <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{partners.image.url}}" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">{{partners.title}}</h4>
            <p class="card-text">{{partners.description}}</p>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="card-block">
            <a href="{{partners.link}}" class="card-link">Card link</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>{% endfor %}
```

Urls are:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path(r'', headpage, name='headpage'),
path(r'about/', about, name='about'),
path(r'partners/$', partners, name='partners'),
```

]

What i do wrong? List of partners isn't displayed..Thank's a lot for your help!

Comment: What *do* you see?

Comment: i see nothing, only base template and free space..No errors

Comment: As an aside the recommendation in Django is to use a singular for the model, e.g. `class Partner(models.Model):`, `partner_list = Partner.objects.all()`, `{% for partner in partner_list %}` and so on.

Comment: i renamed all, deleted db, made new migrations and created 2 partners - nothing:(

Comment: If there are definitely partners in the database, then the most likely problem is that you're not rendering that template snippet. You haven't shown your TEMPLATE settings, or project layout (or even said what the name of that template is), so we can't give any specific help. Try installing the Django Debug Toolbar, it might help you figure out what the problem is.

Comment: I can't spot any problems in the code you've shown. Try the debug toolbar as I suggested.

Comment: if i were i bit better in programming and english, i suppose i'd find a problem using debug toolbar) I realised that the problem is in importing model, because django says me: dude, "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/uzer/PSM/PSMsite/main_app/views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .models import Partners
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.models'; '__main__' is not a package". But i always did like that and had no problems till today..And debugger shows me trouble with the same 2nd string - importing ".models"

Comment: why does it write me 'no module named main_app'? i registered it in INSTALLED_APPS in settings..

Comment: Ah, sorry!) Template's name's partners.html

Comment: I've solved the problem! I didn't say that 'partners.html' is included into about.html - and that was the trouble. I still do not understand why that? 'about.html' extends from the 'base.html' which contains '{% block content %}'. Then i do {% include 'partners.html' %} into block 'content' in 'abou.html'. 'partners.html' has only iteration {% for partners in partners_list %}...{% endfor %}. I'll think about it tomorrow) Thank you a lot for your help!! Best wishes!

Answer (score 0):

You have a dollar in your path. Remove it.

```
path(r'partners/$', partners, name='partners'),
```

Your view and template look OK. First, make sure that the view is actually using the template that you have shown in your question. If the loop does not display anything in the template, that suggests that you don't have any partners in the database. You could check by adding `print(partners_list)` to the view. The Django Debug Toolbar can be useful for debugging problems like this.

Comment: unfortunatelly, still doesn't work...I created few partners through base django admin template..

Comment: @PavelLisitsyn what happens if you print(partners_list), does it show a QuerySet with your Objects or just a empty one?

Comment: when i try to print that - appers next message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 20, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
KeyError: "'__name__' not in globals" (it's about import of Partners class from .models)

Comment: You shouldn't get a name error if you put `print(partners_list)` on the line after `partners_list = Partners.objects.all()` in the view.